# Color image boundary based on local curvature

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am searching for an algorithm (using OpenCV C or C++) which does this:

[image]

Given the boundary image, I want to find the local curvature at all points and color map it, which is what is done in the image displayed above. I got this image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) but haven't been able to find out a way to color the boundary in this way. Kindly let me know how it can be done.

If you observe the boundary, red denotes boundary has high slope, yellow shows that the boundary is almost linear.

How can this be done?

**Edit**

Just to give you an idea of how I was trying to do this since two days:

I used the openCV functions `convexHull` and `convexityDefects` but realized that I am going in the wrong direction. I have to work only on the contours/boundaries of the binary image.

Comment: If anyone opts to close this question, please let me know the reason. I have spent 2 days on it and still couldn't figure out how to find local curvatures in a boundary.

Comment: To detect borders you can use some *convolution matrix". Curvature can be calculated by finding the radius of the circumference through three points. There are plenty of info in the Web.

Comment: Yes, i can also use openCV function `findContours` to detect borders. After that? 

I was not able to proceed after this. How can I find the three points to compute radius of curvature? I am new to this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by fitting a path of cubic Bezier curves to the boundary, then taking the curvature analytically.

[elaborated]

The boundary consists of a list of points in x, y at pixel centres, each point 1px or root 2 px form the next in the list. You need to fit a smooth cubic Bezier path to this, using a technique by Schnider in Graphics Gems (Gems 1, pp 612, An algorithm for Fitting digitized curves).

The step along the curve taking tiny steps which are always sub-pixel, and
take the curvature using

```
double BezierCurve::Curvature(double t) const
    {
        // Nice mathematically perfect formula
        //Vector2 d1 = Tangent(t);
        //Vector2 d2 = Deriv2(t);
        //return (d1.x * d2.y - d1.y * d2.x) / pow(d1.x * d1.x + d1.y * d1.y, 1.5);

        // Get the cubic coefficients like this, I store them in the Bezier
        // class
        /*
        a = p3 + 3.0 * p1 - 3.0 * p2 - p0;
        b = 3.0 * p0 - 6.0 * p1 + 3.0 * p2;
        c = 3.0 * p1 - 3.0 * p0;
        d = p0;
        */


        double dx, dy, ddx, ddy;

        dx = 3 * this->ax * t*t + 2 * this->bx * t + this->cx;
        ddx = 6 * this->ax * t + 2 * this->bx;
        dy = 3 * this->ay * t*t + 2 * this->by * t + this->cy;
        ddy = 6 * this->ay * t + 2 * this->by;

        if (dx == 0 && dy == 0)
            return 0;

        return (dx*ddy - ddx*dy) / ((dx*dx + dy*dy)*sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy));

    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV `findContours` used with mode= CV_RETR_EXTERNAL and method= CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE will give you all boundary pixels ordered such as two subsequent points are neighbors.

To get the radius of a circumference by three points, there are a lot of info in the Web. Because you only need the radius, not the center, [this stackexchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/213678) is fast.

In pseudo code:

```
vector_of_points = OpenCV::findContours(...)
p1 = vector start
p2, p3 are next points in vector

//boundary is circular, so in the first loop pass we must adjust
p2 = next point
p3 = last point

//Use p1 as our iterator
while ( p1 <= vector.end )
{
    //curvature    
    radius = calculateRadius(p1, p2, p3)
    //set color for pixel p2
    setColor(p, radius)

    increment p1, p2, p3
    adjust for start point = end point
}
```